# Thingsboard REST API - How to impersonate another tenant

Tags: thingsboard

When i'm logged in as sysadmin in the Gui, i can use
Tenants → Manage Tenant Admins → Login as Tenant Admin
to become a specific tenant admin.

How can i accomplish this, using the REST API?

I need to add/remove/modify devices on behalf of serveral
tenants.

I tried to authenticate as sysadmin and use /api/tenant/devices
hoping to have access to *all* devices. But this doesn't do
the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sysadmin is not allowed to manage devices, tenant admins are allowed to mange them. Therefore, you need to impersonate a tenant admin. Assuming that you already know the user_id of the tenant admin, you can call to

```
   curl -X 'GET' \
      'https://thingsboard.cloud:443/api/user/{user_id_to_impersonate}/token' \
      -H 'accept: application/json'
```

Extract of Thingsboard documentation: https://thingsboard.cloud/swagger-ui/#/user-controller/getUserTokenUsingGET

> Returns the token of the User based on the provided User Id. If the user who performs the request has the authority of 'SYS_ADMIN', it is possible to get the token of any tenant administrator. If the user who performs the request has the authority of 'TENANT_ADMIN', it is possible to get the token of any customer user that belongs to the same tenant.

Then you can use this token for accessing as another user.

Notice those restrictions: you can impersonate a tenant admin from a System administrator and a user from a tenant admin.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to login via REST API with E-Mail & Password of the desired Tenant Admin:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"username":"tenant@thingsboard.org", "password":"tenant"}' 'http://THINGSBOARD_URL/api/auth/login'
```

This will return the JWT Token needed for further API requests e.g. deleting devices:

> Now, you should set ‘X-Authorization’ header to “Bearer
> $YOUR_JWT_TOKEN”. Make sure you use main JWT token and not the refresh
> token.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately i do not know the passwords of the other Tenant Admins... That is the problem... I have no problem with authentication with known credentials.

Comment: Ok I see, if you have access via sysadmin you are able to create new tenant admins for this purpose.